# hibernate with java.sql.BatchUpdateException

Tags: database, oracle, hibernate, exception

I am using hibernate to map our classes to tables in oracle.
My class has a primary key as id , gets automatically generated by hibernate

```
 <id name="jobId" type="long">
        <column name="JOBID" />
        <generator class="increment" />
    </id>
```

In my code I do:

```
Job job = new Job();
do some config for the job.
saveOrUpdate(job);
```

At this saveOrUpdate I encountered:

```
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
at com.myCompany.BasicDaoImpl.saveOrUpdate(BasicDaoImpl.java:37)
at com.myCompany.JobRoutine.generateJob(JobRoutine.java:142)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (DBGROUP.SYS_C0011345) violated

at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwBatchUpdateException(DatabaseError.java:343)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10700)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:1723)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
... 13 more
```

I find the constraint is priamry_key. 
This error not happy always, but sometimes.

Could anyone please give me some suggestion about it?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

[The documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e5294) says:

> increment
>
> generates identifiers of type long, short or int that are unique only when no other process is inserting data into the same table. Do
>   not use in a cluster.

You probably have another process inserting rows in the same table, and Hibernate is unaware of it, because the increment generator just storesthe next value in memory and assumes it's the only one to insert rows in this table.